Applying the same number of elements in two surfaces
I have this geometry that I insert as  a step file. The problem is that GMSH does not add the same amount of elements on the cylinders of the picture, the one has 134 nodes and the other 140. How can I make the number of nodes equal?
enter image description here
I tried to change the min/Max element size but it doesn't work. I tried to put the surfaces in groups  but again it didn't work.
file:///E:/Users/Giannis/%CE%A3%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1%20%CE%BB%CE%AE%CF%88%CE%B7%CF%82/kelvin_cell_.html

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
